US state tax as credit in India?
I paid Michigan taxes during my few months' stay in the USA in FY23-24. I am a resident of India for the FY23-24. Can I apply for state taxes paid in the US (Michigan) as a credit in Indian tax returns? I know that I can use Fed tax as a credit. The following question has two different answers:
Are U.S. Social Security payroll contributions and state taxes deductible from taxable income for India?
